# Using production or dev firebase app based on build mode in flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, web

While developing a flutter web app, I was using the dev firebase project. Now, when the development is finished it is required to use the production firebase project for production. How can this be done other then simply swapping the firebase dev configuration from index.html with the prod firebase config before building the app.
[image]

I tried this tutorial [Dynamic HTML elements](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dynamic-html-elements-an-approach-to-flavors-in-flutter-web-6bff1a7d655a) but I couldn't adapt it to my solution.

[image]

I thought that the configuration could be added as a child but an error was thrown:

> Expected a value of type 'Element', but got one of type 'FirebaseOptions'

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this, I am also trying to do the similar setup. And firebase init errors out, as the plugin registration happens before firebase is inited on web.

Comment: the same issue is with me. did anyone ever find a solution?